# Reuse/forward OAuth2 authorization code grant from one resource server to another

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I need to implement a kinda "bff" but with oauth2 authorisation code grant. Like, client requests a rest endpoint from "bff", "bff" acts like a resource server; then bff queries rest endpoints from multiple services with feign. These services act as a resource servers for this "bff". Then, "bff" should process the responses, making its own response, and send it to the client then. Something like "Authorization" header forwarding, I suppose. But have no idea how to implement it. Maybe something like spring cloud gateway but a bit more intelligent. Or, maybe it is possible to implement a filter that will just relay this header?

Any documentation or better small but complete code sample would be just great. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### RequestInterceptor

What you are looking for is probably a `RequestInterceptor`. In a Spring boot app, exposing one as a `@Component` or `@Bean` (it is a functional interface you can implement with a lambda) should be enough.

This could be implemented:

- on an OAuth2 resource server:

```java
@Bean
RequestInterceptor resourceServerBearerRequestInterceptor() {
    return (RequestTemplate template) -> {
        final var auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() instanceof ServletRequestAttributes servletRequestAttributes) {
            if (auth instanceof AbstractOAuth2TokenAuthenticationToken oauth) {
                template.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer %s".formatted(oauth.getToken().getTokenValue()));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

- on an OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login`

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ClientBearerRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepo;
    
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        final var auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() instanceof ServletRequestAttributes servletRequestAttributes) {
            if (auth instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauth) {
                final var authorizedClient = authorizedClientRepo.loadAuthorizedClient(oauth.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), auth, servletRequestAttributes.getRequest());
                if (authorizedClient != null) {
                    template.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer %s".formatted(authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If your app is not a Boot app (or if you define your `RequestInterceptor` out of `@ComponentScan`), you could have to provide the configuration class as `@FeignClient(configuration = ...)`

### About the BFF pattern

The pattern in the question drawing is now discouraged for security reasons:

- requires to configure the frontends as "public" OAuth2 clients
- exposes tokens (all of it) to the internet and Javascript / mobile apps code

As defined in an [ITEF document](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bertocci-oauth2-tmi-bff-01) linked by the author of the question in the comments a "Full BFF" is an acronym for backends configured as **OAuth2 clients bridging between session authorization (for the frontends) and `Bearer` header authorization for the requests it forwards to resource servers**. However, the pattern exposed in this document diverges from the Full BFF: the OAuth2 client (what retrieves OAuth2 tokens from the authorization server) is on the backend but the BFF exposes access tokens to the frontend so that it can call resource servers directly and session authorization is used only to retrieve access tokens (motivation for this quite unusual pattern is performance, apparently).

##### "Full BFF" pattern

To my knowledge, [Spring Security team recommendations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390) is to hide tokens from mobile or Javascript based web apps, and to have it query OAuth2 clients using sessions. Also, all major web apps I know (Google, Facebook, Github, Stackoverflow, Linkedin, and so many more) apply this pattern: **inspect those web apps with your browser debugging tools, you won't find a single access token (just session cookies)**.

`spring-cloud-gateway` is a perfect fit to implement a "Full BFF" when configured with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` (with `oauth2Login` and CSRF protection), and `TokenRelay=` filter (this filter replaces the session cookie with the access token in session before forwarding a request). Also, it scales very well when used with Spring Session, which removes the limitation motivating the usage of a "non Full" BFF as exposed in the ITEF document linked above.

**I have written a [Full BFF tutorial for Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2)**, but be aware that it is using an additional [starter of mine](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc) to ease security configuration and that you should probably read [pro and cons](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc#drawbacks) before using such a lib (this latest link also contains references to instructions for writing security conf without my starter).

##### [ITEF document BFF](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bertocci-oauth2-tmi-bff-01)

To implement the pattern described in the ITEF document linked by the question author, where the BFF fetches and stores tokens but exposes access tokens to frontends so that it can call resource servers directly, the BFF app configured as both:

- an OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login` to expose an endpoint retrieving the access token value from the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`, using the `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` in the security context
- an OAuth2 resource server to answer REST requests authorized with an access token the frontend got from the endpoint just above

For that, you'll need two `SecurityFilterChain` beans: one with OAuth2 client conf for login and the access-token endpoint, and another one with OAuth2 resource server conf for REST endpoints. This filter-chains beans will need to have

- different names
- distinct `@Order`
- the first in `@Order` must define a `securityMatcher` to define which requests it should process

For a servlet app and using [a starter of mine](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons#oidc-starter) to ease security config, this would give something like:

```java
@Component
public class ResourceServerBearerRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        final var auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() instanceof ServletRequestAttributes servletRequestAttributes) {
            if (auth instanceof AbstractOAuth2TokenAuthenticationToken oauth) {
                template.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer %s".formatted(oauth.getToken().getTokenValue()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@FeignClient(name = "quizzes", url = "${spring.cloud.openfeign.client.quizzes.url}")
public interface QuizClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/quizzes")
    List<QuizDto> getAllQuizzes();
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Validated
@Tag(name = "QuizProxy")
public class QuizProxyController {
    
    private final QuizClient quizzes;

    @GetMapping("/proxy/quizzes")
    public Integer getAccessToken() {
        return quizzes.getAllQuizzes().size();
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Validated
@Tag(name = "AccessToken")
public class AccessTokenController {
    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepo;

    @GetMapping("/access-token")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public AccessTokenDto getAccessToken(OAuth2AuthenticationToken auth, HttpServletRequest request) {
        final var authorizedClient = authorizedClientRepo.loadAuthorizedClient(auth.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), auth, request);
        return authorizedClient == null
                ? null
                : new AccessTokenDto(authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue(), authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getExpiresAt().getEpochSecond());
    }

    public static record AccessTokenDto(String accessToken, long expiry) {
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
}
```

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

```yaml
scheme: http
oauth2-issuer: https://oidc.c4-soft.com/auth/realms/quiz
oauth2-client-id: quiz-bff
oauth2-client-secret: change-me
frontend: ${scheme}://localhost:4200
quizzes-resources: ${scheme}://localhost:7084

server:
  port: 8080
  error:
    include-message: always
  shutdown: graceful
  ssl:
    enabled: false
    

spring:
  config:
    import:
    - optional:configtree:/workspace/config/
    - optional:configtree:/workspace/secret/
  lifecycle:
    timeout-per-shutdown-phase: 30s
  cloud:
    openfeign:
      client:
        quizzes:
          url: ${quizzes-resources}
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          c4:
            issuer-uri: ${oauth2-issuer}
        registration:
          c4:
            provider: c4
            authorization-grant-type: authoriztion_code
            client-id: ${OAuth2-client-ID} 
            client-secret: ${OAuth2-client-secret} 
            scope:
            - openid
            - profile
            - email
            - offline_access
          
com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: ${oauth2-issuer}
          username-claim: preferred_username
          authorities:
          - path: $.resource_access.${oauth2-client-id}.roles
        client:
          security-matchers:
          - /login/**
          - /oauth2/**
          - /access-token
          permit-all:
          - /login/**
          - /oauth2/**
          cors:
          - path: /**
            allowed-origin-patterns:
            - ${frontend}
          post-login-redirect-host: ${frontend}
          post-login-redirect-path: /
          post-logout-redirect-host: ${frontend}
          post-logout-redirect-path: /
        resourceserver:
          permit-all:
          - "/proxy/**"
          - "/actuator/health/readiness"
          - "/actuator/health/liveness"
          - "/v3/api-docs/**"
          cors:
          - path: /**
            allowed-origin-patterns:
            - ${frontend}
        
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      probes:
        enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
  health:
    livenessstate:
      enabled: true
    readinessstate:
      enabled: true

logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        security: TRACE

---
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: ssl
```

Please note that in addition to adding quite some complexity to both front and back ends (compared to Full BFF), such a solution solves only some of known vulnerabilities for frontends configured as "public" clients:

- a "confidential" client can be used on the backend
- refresh tokens (which are the most sensitive ones) can remain on the server

But **access tokens are still exposed to Javascript or mobile apps code**.

Considering how well `spring-cloud-gateway` scales with Spring session, I'm personally more inclined to implement "Full BFF".

Comment: afaik, there's no common definition for bff, nor requirement to replace oauth2 with session cookie. bff is just a pattern for aggregating and filtering data required by the fe. I suppose, it's not a good idea to such a "replacement". Regarding picking token - I could pick the token from the request and pass it to the response in each controller or using filter, but I just wonder is there a "native" spring way to do that.

Comment: you could read more here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/backends-for-frontends
and here:
https://samnewman.io/patterns/architectural/bff/

Comment: I agree there is no standard definition for BFF. However, your second article is almost ten years old, and to be honest I found too frequently inconsistencies in Microsoft doc to trust it.

Comment: Using "confidential" clients is way safer than using "public" ones. It is also safer that OAuth2 access (and refresh) tokens remain on the server rather than transit over the internet, are exposed to application code running on random devices on which it is stored more or less securely. This is a reason why serious **recent** articles talking about securing mobile or Javascript based apps will configure a BFF as an OAuth2 client and a mechanism like TokenRelay. Just inspect Gmail, Facebook, Github, etc., in your browser debug tools, you'll find just session cookies (no access token)

Comment: I think that the only occurrence of "BFF" in spring security doc is [this one](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/getting-started.html#security-use-cases). All the doc further linked from there references client conf. For instance "I need to [login using OAuth 2.0 or OIDC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html)"

Comment: really, have no time to argue. I've got a task which im trying to accomplish

Comment: So, yes, the way you started is possible (and I even explain how to proceed in my answer), but no, it is not considered a best practice any more to configure mobile or Javascript based applications as "public" OAuth2 clients (even with PKCE)

Comment: I've got a simple question. It's quite easy to get the bearer token from the request and put it to the response. My only question was "how to do that spring-natively?"

Comment: If you're in a hurry, you'd better consider writing something you won't have to trash and rewrite the next day. I strongly suggest you take five minutes to read about BFF from Spring Security authors: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390

Comment: Browser-based applications:

MUST use the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code flow with the PKCE extension when obtaining an access token

Comment: and just a few lines further (in the BFF paragraph) "This enables the ability to perform OAuth flows in the backend component and store the access token and refresh token in the "secure" server environment instead of the "insecure" frontend (browser) environment" So yes, the authorization code flow is used, but the client is the BFF and the browser never accesses tokens.

Comment: The fun thing being this paragraph links to the same [article from 2015](https://samnewman.io/patterns/architectural/bff/) that you linked earlier. So Spring Security team and you have the same definition for BFF, but they recommand a quite different Security configuration.

Comment: exactly. also https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bertocci-oauth2-tmi-bff-01

Comment: so, "BFF is an acronym more frequently used for backends configured as OAuth2 clients bridging between session authorization (for the frontends) and Bearer header authorization for the requests it forwards to resource servers." simply isn't true, sorry

Comment: Yep, according to the ITEF document you just link, I should have written "Full BFF": __Although the Full BFF approach offers better security, by virtue of keep all tokens out of the user agent__. Will edit my answer to fix that. For your information, `spring-cloud-gateway` along with Spring Session scale pretty well and you must be writing hell of an app to expect billions of requests a month...

Comment: oh my, please lets stop. "For the sake of clarity, in this document we will use Full BFF to refer to the approach where both token acquisition and API invocation are handled by the backend, and BFF for approaches where the frontend retain the responsibility to implement some functionality (as it is the case for the pattern described in this specification)."

Comment: I reworked the answer adding reference to the `RequestInterceptor` interface (which is probably what you are looking for) and to be more specific about "Full" (or not) BFF. Also, thank you for the link to the ITEF resource, I have been looking for such a rather standard BFF definition for a while (and didn't know about this non-Full BFF definition)

Comment: Have you noticed that you have a way to automatically set the Authorization header for all of your `@FeignClient` requests in this answer?

Comment: Sorry for delay, i'll check and return back a bit later. Yes, I see you use filter to set header to every request. It isn't good 'cause potentially there could be requests that either not require (and should not expose) or require different auth. I'll probably stay with "per request" header cppying

Comment: You could define configuration properties with a mapping of `template.feignTarget().url()` or `template.url()` for which to include an access token (and from which issuer / client if you have several)

Comment: It means that with each new url, I (or someone else) would have not forget to modify it. Much simpler to relay header directly in the controller, I suppose

Comment: Sorry for delay, my bad. At last ive got some time to read your answer. Great, thank you so much!

Comment: And could you give me (and others) a favour and mention in the answer, that it is possible to create a configuration class with RequestInterceptor bean, then to specify this class in the ```@FeignClient(configuration=ConfigClass.class)```

Comment: Done, but note that, [as demoed there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui/src/main/java/com/c4soft/springaddons/tutorials/ui/GreetClient.java), this shouldn't be necessary in a boot app.